# how to get only the deleted / added lines by git diff command?

Tags: git

Is it possible to figure out only the deleted lines of a file by `git diff` command?

Currently `git diff` shows both the modified lines and deleted lines shown in the picture.

[image: git diff]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do that using `bash` would be:

`git diff | grep "^-[^-]"` , it keeps only the lines starting with a `-` and do not have a second character `-` following, intended to avoid printing the files that contain the change.

Comment: That breaks if any line that starts with `-` is removed, as it would produce the same pattern you try to filter as the header.